# How to enable verbose output using the ant task and inheritall="false"

Tags: ant, build-process

When starting a build in verbose mode (ant -v) the verbose mode is not propagated to the "subants". The ant task looks like this:

```
<ant antfile="${buildproject}" inheritall="false" target="${target}" output="${output.file}">           
  <property name="repo.global" value="/repo"/>
  <property name="proj.property.prefix" value="${property_prefix}"/>        
</ant>
```

We don't want to propagate all properties because we try to remove an old build system. Any ideas how to preserve the "verbose" output without using the exec task?

Comment: see this, on how to use javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462732/make-ant-quiet-without-the-q-flag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to deal with something similar just last month. You probably need to define you own task to change the loglevel in a script. The following blog entry (http://codefeed.com/blog/?p=82) helped a lot. The author provides all the necessary source code.

Comment: This seems to be the answer. I'll try it next week using an script task.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create your own task with all that hassle, there is a embedded-javascript-snippet [answer in this SO-question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5465088/39334).