# Is it possible to specify logger for ant inside build.xml?

Tags: ant

Is it possible specify Ant [listener/logger](http://ant.apache.org/manual/listeners.html) inside `build.xml`, not on a command line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within the buildfile it's possible to make use of the ant api and create an internal task via `scriptdef`.
i.e. implemented with groovy:

<strike>http://josefbetancourt.wordpress.com/2011/08/18/buildlistener-groovy-scriptdef/</strike>
http://octodecillion.com/blog/buildlistener-groovy-scriptdef/

It's also possible to adjust the loglevel inside the buildfile, see :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5464009/130683
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5479606/130683

Answer (score 3):

It's not in the build file, but you can set the ANT_ARGS env variable to specify the logger

http://wiki.apache.org/ant/TheElementsOfAntStyle

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `Recorder` task.
http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/recorder.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<target name="real-build">
   <exec dir="${basedir}" executable="${ant.command}" failonerror="true">
    <arg line="-f build-all.xml target ${ant.logger}" />
   </exec>
</target>
```

Comment: This is not inside build.xml but opening a new java process with a new ant instance instead, similar to use the command line option -logger .. btw. assuming ${ant.logger} is -logger ... it should be arg line= ${ant.logger} -f ... => ant [options] [target [target2 [target3] ...]], see http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html#options.