# Color (red/green) console output for ant junit tests

Tags: java, ant, junit

I'm playing with `ant` and `JUnit4` in a terminal emulator, *not* in an IDE like Eclipse.

Is there an ant-native method of getting colorised test results? A google search led me to [this python script](https://github.com/eevans/color-junit); I'd prefer to utilize 'pure' `ant` if I can.

For example, when I run my tests with `ant runtests`, I'd like to display the `FAILED` tests red, the `PASSED` tests green, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [AnsiColorLogger](http://ant.apache.org/manual/listeners.html#AnsiColorLogger) described in the [Ant manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html) should do exactly what you want.

Comment: Set the `ANT_ARGS` environmental variable to automate the `-logger` argument; see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5733003/1084945) and links.