# How to enable AnsiColorLogger by default in Apache Ant?

Tags: apache, logging, ant

How can I enable the [**AnsiColorLogger**](https://ant.apache.org/manual/listeners.html#AnsiColorLogger) Apache Ant built-in **logger** by default without running manually command `ant -logger org.apache.tools.ant.listener.AnsiColorLogger` or adding the environment variable `ANT_ARGS` ?

---

I tried to run the command from the ant build. 
**build.xml**

```
<exec dir="${sdk.dir}" executable="cmd">
    <arg value="${sdk.dir}" />
    <arg value="AnsiColorLogger.cmd" />
</exec>
```

**AnsiColorLogger.cmd**

```
START -logger org.apache.tools.ant.listener.AnsiColorLogger
```

Then I run the `ant` command to compile my project but the logs are not colored.

```
Fuiba@FUIBA D:\DEV\TEST\proj
> ant
Buildfile: D:\DEV\TEST\proj\build.xml
Trying to override old definition of task for
     [exec] Microsoft Windows [Versione 10.0.10240]
     [exec] (c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. Tutti i diritti sono riservati.
     [exec]
     [exec] Fuiba@FUIBA D:\DEV\TEST\proj
     [exec] >
```

Instead when I run `ant -logger org.apache.tools.ant.listener.AnsiColorLogger` it works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to specify logger for ant inside build.xml?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721513/is-it-possible-to-specify-logger-for-ant-inside-build-xml)

Comment: @ChadNouis Thank you! but that does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you say you run ant directly it works, how are you running it? From ant's own documentation it doesn't support Windows NT derivatives (including Windows 8 , 10, etc). From your output, it looks like you're running on Windows, so please go into more detail on how to reproduce this problem.

From ant's manual:

> Note: It doesn't work on WinNT and successors, even when a COMMAND.COM console loaded with ANSI.SYS is used.

Source: https://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html

If you are running ant from within a terminal that supports ANSI escape sequences, like Cygwin's MinTTY or CMDER, you try passing the `env` argument to your exec task:

```xml
<exec dir="${sdk.dir}" executable="cmd">
    <env key="ANT_ARGS" value="-logger org.apache.tools.ant.listener.AnsiColorLogger"/>
    <arg value="${sdk.dir}" />
    <arg value="AnsiColorLogger.cmd" />
</exec>
```

- Commander: https://cmder.net/
- Cygwin: https://cygwin.com/