# How to suppress ANT Copy Message

Tags: ant, build, logging

He Guys,

i wonder how to suppress ANT `[copy]` and `[mkdir]`  notifications like `Copied 2 empty directories to 2 empty directories under…` during the Build process.

Maybe it's impossible but does anyone has some suggestions for me?

Regards

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462732/make-ant-quiet-without-the-q-flag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write and install your own custom listener or logger. See the [ant documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/listeners.html)