# Apache Ant: turn off output for a specific task

Tags: ant, build-process, build-automation

I have a build file that has different variety of tasks. Some of these are in-house tasks that I am able to control the amount of logging/output generated.

The other tasks are libraries that I have no control over. They do not provide a way to control the amount of output. There is one very trivial task and I am comfortable with turning off the output of the task all together.

My question is if there a way to turn off this specific tasks output in the ant execution. Or does ant provide a way to wrap this task in another task that has echo set to 'off' or something similar?

-Syam

Answer (score 5):

Ant has no builtin feature to turn off output for specific task, but there are possibilities via buildlisteners. See [Make ant quiet without the -q flag?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5462732/130683) for answers

Answer (score 5):

outputproperty="devnull"

It works fine for me and allways you can print this var if you need.