# How can I debug a chown task in Ant?

Tags: debugging, shell, ant, build, build-automation

We have an Ant script with a chown task as follows:

```
<chown owner="${user}" verbose="true">
   <fileset dir="${dev-home}" includes="**/**"/>
   <dirset dir="${dev-home}" includes="**/**"/>
</chown>
```

The task is failing, but just says that it fails without stating why or giving the command that was being executed. How can we debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may run your Ant file in debug mode by:

```
ant -debug -f yourbuildfile.xml
```

For debugging specific parts use the techniques described in this thread: [Make ant quiet without the -q flag?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5462732/130683)

Check also [Ant's manual for `chown` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/chown.html) which reads:

> If you are working on a large number of files this may result in a command line that is too long for your operating system. If you encounter such problems, you should set the `maxparallel` attribute of this task to a non-zero value. The number to use highly depends on the length of your file names (the depth of your directory tree) and your operating system, so you'll have to experiment a little.